# Unit testing a method that uses reflection

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, junit

I am trying to unit test some java methods like this one:

```
public boolean isInt (Object object){
    return object.getClass().equals(Integer.class);
}
```

This is an extremely simple example but lets go with it.

The question is: How can you unit test (with JUnit) a method like that without writing a test for each primitive type in the java world? Maybe the [Concolic Unit Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concolic_testing) ([jCute](http://osl.cs.illinois.edu/software/jcute/)) is the answer?

Please leave your ideas, I would like to make the test as thorough as possible with the less coding possible.

EDIT: The goal of the unit test is to check that the method is returning the correct result for any type different than Integer, without having to define a set of tests checking all types one by one.  When I said primitives I meant the native types from the JDK (String, Float, Double, List, Map, ...)

Comment: Primitive has a very specific meaning in Java and does not include List or Map. Your edit basically says that you want to test all classes defined in the JDK. I don't think there is an easy way to do it and I don't see the point. It's as if you were saying: "*I have this method: `double mult(double a, double b) { return a * b; }` and I want to check that it works for any doubles*". In real life, you would only test corner cases, say (1,0), (0,1), (0,0), (0,Infinity), (1,Infinity) etc. and a few normal cases, like (2,3).

Comment: In the context of the project it has a point. When you are trying to insert a POJO into database rows, for instance, you want to check that the methods you use can deal with almost anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limited list of primitive types: byte, short, int, long, boolean, char. Each primitive has corresponding wrapper. That's it. So, it is really easy to write test for each primitive type.

BTW you code cannot work for primitieves because they are not objects, so you cannot call `isInt(123)`.

If you want to write shorter tests you can write something like:

```
@Test
public void isInt() {
    assertTrue(obj.isInt(new Integer(1)));
}

@Test
public void isNotInt() {
    for (Object obj : new Object[] {new Short(1), new Boolean(true), new Long(1), new Chaeracter('a')}) {
        assertFalse(obj.isInt(obj));
    }

}
```

JUnit also supportes `Parametrized` tests. However this sounds as an overkill for such simple case.

Comment: Not sure I get this: *so you cannot call `isInt(123)`*. Also you are missing Float and Double in your array.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really test *all* types against your method - so I would keep it simple:

```
assertTrue(isInt(1)); //an Integer
assertFalse(isInt(1d); //another Number that is not an Integer
assertFalse(isInt(new Object())); //a random Object
```

You may want to add a test for `null` too (is it supposed to throw a NPE?).

Comment: And you are getting all possible types with the `new Object()` declaration?

Comment: No you are not - I just don't see the point of testing all primitive types. But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I edited the question clarifying the goal of the test